# Custom ListView in Fragment just appear when I rotate the Android Phone

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-listview

I have created an Fragment to be the main feed of my app. The list data(ArrayList) is loaded from the main activity through the inner interface in fragment that Activity implements.

My problems:

1. My custom ListView just is shown when I rotate de phone.
2. OnCreateView and OnActivityCreate is called twice when I rotate.
3. If ListView is shown after I rotate the phone and I click in, i get next error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131034209, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.fb.newcomersapp.CustomListAdapter)]

That is my main fragment methods:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.event_list_view);
    mCallback.parseQueryEvents();
    ArrayList<Event> eventList = mCallback.getEventList();
    Log.d("FeedActivity", eventList.size()+"");
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), eventList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCallback.openEvent(position);

        }
    });

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
    textView.setText(mCallback.getLocal()); 
    return view;
}
```

The main activity methods:

```
public void parseQueryEvents () {
    eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
    query.orderByAscending("startDate") ;
    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("endDate", new Date()) ;
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseEventList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ParseObject temp ;
                Iterator<ParseObject> i = parseEventList.iterator() ;
                while(i.hasNext()) {
                    temp = i.next();
                    eventList.add(new Event(temp)) ;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("FeedActivity", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<Event> getEventList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return eventList;
}
```

Log:

> 02-04 13:36:06.844: D/GPS(7237): GPS
>   02-04 13:36:07.110: D/FeedActivity(7237): 0
>   02-04 13:36:07.145: D/GPS(7237): GPS
>   02-04 13:36:07.409: D/FeedActivity(7237): 0
>   02-04 13:36:07.420: I/Choreographer(7237): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-04 13:36:07.451: W/View(7237): requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{42079068 IFED.VC. ......ID -360,0-0,778 #7f050041 app:id/list_slidermenu} during layout: running second layout pass

So, anyone can help me? Thx :D

Comment: Are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the ListAdapter in the onCreate() ?

Comment: @joaquin No, but is in onCreate from Acvitivity or onActivityCreated from Fragment? I just have to call notifyDateSetChanged with adapter as paramter?

Comment: Try putting that in the onCreateView of each fragment

Comment: I ran into this problem a while ago when dealing with orientation changes. Sorry for not giving a full answer atm, but basically save the adapter (as well as the ListView if you'd like) as a class variable. Then, inside onActivityCreated, put the lines about creating and setting the adapter in a if statement checking if the adapter is null or not

Comment: I believe the issue originates somewhere along the line where it's trying to save us all some time by caching variables (like the ListView) when recreating the Activity+Fragment. However, here you are trying to set another Adapter when the old adapter is already on and confused~.
(yeah, not a well-defined, complete explanation, which is why I didn't want to answer xD )

Comment: @joaquin I put adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, but did not work for me. I am grateful by answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a while ago when dealing with orientation changes. Sorry for not giving a full answer atm, but basically save the adapter (as well as the ListView if you'd like) as a class variable. Then, inside onActivityCreated, put the lines about creating and setting the adapter in a if statement checking if the adapter is null or not. So, something like this...

```
private CustomListAdapter mAdapter; // Add this variable

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.event_list_view);
    mCallback.parseQueryEvents();
    ArrayList<Event> eventList = mCallback.getEventList();
    Log.d("FeedActivity", eventList.size()+"");

    // Add this conditional
    if(mAdapter == null) {
       CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), eventList);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCallback.openEvent(position);

        }
    }
}
```

I believe the issue originates somewhere along the line where it's trying to save us all some time by caching variables (like views with ids such as the ListView) when recreating the Activity+Fragment- however, in the midst of all that, setting a new adapter causes an issue.

Comment: That did not work for me. Maybe in another context it would work. Thx by the answer. I updated the question, I put the log.

Comment: Sorry about the incomplete answer, that only took down the third problem (if even that), didn't it? However, how is your Activity and Fragment interfacing? I can't see when the Fragment's callback is set. Also, on a side note, what if parseQueryEvents is called more than once? (try to see if that causes an issue normally)

Those are both potential bugs

Comment: Also, if the app still crashes after adding the above code, please post the corresponding full Logcat error (including where it lists line numbers)